# angular cannot seem to understand text with spaces in $watch expression

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to add a `$watch` to a model property, and I'm running into an issue where, if the initial value has a space, it throws an error; this is how I've set it up.

```
$scope.$watch($scope.Name, function (n, o) {
   console.log('updating name: ', n);
});
```

This corresponds to the HTML ...

```
<span name="name" contenteditable strip-br="true" ng-model="Name" class="profile-name" />
```

I am using the following binding to work with `contenteditable`

```
angular.module('ui.editable', ['ngSanitize']).
directive('contenteditable', ['$sce','$sanitize', function($sce, $sanitize) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            // Specify how UI should be updated
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                element.html($sanitize(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
            };

            // Listen for change events to enable binding
            element.on('blur keyup change', function () {
                scope.$apply(readViewText);
            });

            // Write data to the model
            function readViewText() {
                var html = element.html();
                // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
                // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
                if (attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>') {
                    html = '';
                }
                ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

altogether, I get this error when I try to run this code

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Lynn' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [Stacey Lynn] starting at [Lynn].

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. I've never encountered something quite like this before.

If the name does not contain spaces, there is no error. Once the watch initializes successfully, there do not appear to be any errors if the value changes to one that contains spaces.

Comment: Have you tried this? `$scope.$watch('Name', function(n, o) {
    console.log('updating name: ', n);
  });`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you. It never even occurred to me.

Comment: Can you post that as an actual answer so I may award credit?

Comment: Yes, Just a moment! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
$scope.$watch('Name', function (n, o) {
    console.log('updating name: ', n);
});
```